# How to POST XML string using RestTemplate

Tags: java, xml, post, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have the following scenario. I have an XML file:

query-users.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<q:query xmlns:q="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3">
</q:query>
```

When executing the curl commend:

```
curl.exe --user administrator:5ecr3t -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X POST http://localhost:8080/midpoint/ws/rest/users/search -d @C:\Users\user\query-users.xml
```

I get the desired response in XML. 
I am trying to do the same POST request using `RestTemplate` from JAVA code:

```
try{    
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("http://localhost:8080/midpoint/ws/rest/users/search");
    builder.append("?query=");
    builder.append(URLEncoder.encode("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><q:query xmlns:q=\"http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/query-3\"></q:query>"));

    URI uri = URI.create(builder.toString());

    restOperations.postForEntity(uri, new HttpEntity<String>(createHeaders("username", "pass")), String.class);
    logger.info(response);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I get `Internal Servel Error` . 
There is something that I am doing wrong passing the XML string to the POST request with `RestTemplate`, but I am not figuring out what it is.

Is there a way how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the server's log? I see you are accessing localhost

Comment: You're not posting your xml in the request body, you're sending it as a query param... this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461148/how-to-send-xml-post-requests-with-spring-resttemplate

Answer (score 0):

Your curl invocation and RestTemplate call are not equivalent. In first one you pass your xml as a a body of HTTP Request (this is what -d option does). In your RestTemplate you assign your xml to query and consequently HTTP Request has no payload and your data is encoded in URL.

If you want to pass your xml as a HTTP Body, you should use different HttpEntity constuctor: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#HttpEntity-T-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-