# Unable to send request parameter using Spring RestTemplate client to HttpServeletRequest doPost

Tags: java, servlets, spring-resttemplate

I am using Spring RestTemplate client to do a POST call to another application which handles this request as HTTpServletRequest.
Problem is HTTpServletRequest is expecting a key value pair e.g.

```
String xmlString = request.getParameter("xml12")
//xmlString should be  "`<parent><child></child></parent>`" but coming as null.
```

Here is the code snippet of both ends -

My app -

```
String data = "`<parent><child></child></parent>`"

HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders()

header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

Map<String,String> bodyParamMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
bodyParamMap.put("xml123",data)

String reqBodyData = new ObjectMapper().writeValuesAsString(bodyParamMap)

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(reqBodyData,header)

RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate()

String response = rt.postForObject("url",entity,String.class)
//Getting response as 500
```

Other app -

```
HttpServletRequest request = new HttpServletRequest()
String xmlString = request.getParameter("xml123")
// xmlString is null
```

I just want to know my mistake and how to pass my data string to post request so that `request.getParameter("xml123")` receives my data xml as String.

Comment: Please attach stacktrace - 
I can guess, that maybe :
- String data - don't need additional single quotes
- You could try 'postForEntity'
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461148/how-to-send-xml-post-requests-with-spring-resttemplate

We absolutely need more information ;)
Cheers !

Comment: String data doesn't have additional single quotes, while posting somehow got added.

Comment: I don't have stacktrace other than log saying 'Internal Server error 500'. Other end I can't fetch the logs.

Comment: The request in working fine with Postman when I do POST with url and adding xml123 and its value under 'x-www-form-urlencoder' section. Point to check is, it works only when I add it under mentioned section. Can somebody help me with this translation to RestTemplate code?