# Generic cast using parenthesis

Tags: java, generics

I tried to understand next thing. This block code will print next

```
example.TestGenerics$One@49c2faae
example.TestGenerics$Two@20ad9418
```

So I suppose that cast was complete successfully, but I expect ClassCastException for second object in list.

```
public class TestGenerics
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Generic<One> integerGeneric = new Generic<One>(new Container(Lists.<Object>newArrayList(new One(), new Two())));
        integerGeneric.checkContainer();
    }

    static class Generic<T>
    {
        private Container container;

        public Generic(Container container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public void checkContainer()
        {
            for (Object key : container.getObjects())
            {
                final T genericKey = (T)key;
                System.out.println(genericKey);
            }
        }
    }

    static class Container
    {
        Iterable<Object> objects;

        public Container(Iterable<Object> objects)
        {
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        public Iterable<Object> getObjects()
        {
            return objects;
        }
    }

    static class One
    {

    }

    static class Two
    {

    }
}
```

P.S.
Also I faced a problem that generic type cast (using (T)object) returns null instead of throwing exception ClassCastExceptiong, but i cant reproduce it. If anyone know about this, comment here, please

Comment: You might want to look up what "type erasure" is and how it works in Java.

Comment: I'm going to bet that you've got an unchecked cast warning in there.

Comment: @Tom, thanks, I have learned that JVM see generic like Object type in runtime (or nearest type, if it has "exists")

Answer (score -2):

> I have learned that JVM see generic like Object type in runtime (or nearest type, if it has "exists")

Not necessarily `Object`. This is the case for unbounded generics, like in your code. If it has a bound, like `<T extends ParentClass>`, then the runtime type would be `ParentClass`. Since your code has no bound it will be `Object` and this wouldn't cause any problem during a cast.

Now, to improve your type checks and to get proper compiler errors, you'll need to add a generic type to `Container`:

```
static class Container<T> {
    Iterable<T> objects;

    public Container(Iterable<T> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public Iterable<T> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }
}
```

And update `Generic` to avoid using a raw `Container` class:

```
static class Generic<T> {
    private Container<T> container;

    public Generic(Container<T> container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void checkContainer() {
        for (T key : container.getObjects()) {
            final T genericKey = key;
            System.out.println(genericKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Now add a [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7) in your main method to:

```
Generic<One> integerGeneric = new Generic<One>(new Container(Lists.<Object>newArrayList(new One(), new Two())));
```

And you'll then have:

```
Generic<One> integerGeneric = new Generic<>(new Container<>(Lists.newArrayList(new One(), new Two())));
```

And a compiler error stating that `Lists.newArrayList(new One(), new Two())` isn't allowed if the desired type is `One`.

---

Btw: you still can bypass this compiler check by either using raw types or `Object` as the generic type and this still won't cause a runtime exception, because both `Container` and `Generic` classes have no bounds.

Comment: If someone wonders about the downvote: [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) used it as one of his targets for his revenge downvotes.