# About Callable<> and List

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I am new in Java.I tried to collect some Callable by List.

```
List<Callable<Long>> callables=new ArrayList<>()
```

But complier gave me "Cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>".
Then I chang the code to :

```
List<Callable<Long>> callables=new LinkedList<>();
```

There is no error message.why I can't use ArrayList to Implement?? Thanks!!

Comment: Post the full code, with imports. This should work if we're talking about `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.List`.

Comment: Do you have your own class named `ArrayList` which is being picked up instead of the standard class `java.util.ArrayList`? Remove it or rename it. Don't give classes the same name as standard classes.

Comment: Without type arguments compiler would complain for both ArrayList and LinkedList. As @Tunaki mentioned, please post full code.

Comment: @SVashisth Well, since Java 7, it would compile both. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Comment: I am so stupid.As whst @Jesper said there is a class named ArrayList in the same package.Aftert I remove it,there is no  error message.Thank everyone!!