# Converting class using an array of references to Point2d objects to using a java.util.ArrayList<Point2d>

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

```
package polygongeneric;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Polygon {

private ArrayList <Point2d> p = null;
private int points = 0;

public Polygon() { }

public Polygon(int numPoints) {
    p = new ArrayList<>();
}

public boolean addPoint(Point2d point) {
   p.add(points, point);
    points++;
    return true;
}

public boolean addPoint(double x, double y) {
   Point2d a = new Point2d(x,y);
   p.add(points, a);
   return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i=0; i<points; i++)
        s += p.get(i).toString() + "\n";
    return s;
}
```

}

I'm trying to convert a class from using an array of references to Point2d objects as type Point2d. This is what I have so far but it's not outputting the answer that it's supposed to.

**This is what my code outputs**

```
(0.1,0.9)

(0.5,0.5)

(0.2,0.5)
```

**This is what it's supposed to output**

```
(0.1,0.9)

(0.3,0.7)

(0.5,0.5)

(0.4,0.8)

(0.2,0.5)
```

Do you guys have any idea. What I'm doing wrong?

**This is my Point2d class**

```
package polygongeneric;

public class Point2d {

private double x = 0, y = 0;

public Point2d() { }

public Point2d(double x, double y) {
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}

public void setX(double initX) {
    if (initX >= 0 && initX <= 1)
        x = initX;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    if (y >= 0 && y <= 1)
        this.y = y;
}

public double getX() { return x; }

public double getY() { return y; }

public String toString() {
    return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

}

**This is my main method**

```
package polygongeneric;

public class PolygonGeneric {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Polygon p = new Polygon(5);

    p.addPoint(new Point2d(.1, .9));
    p.addPoint(.3, .7);
    p.addPoint(new Point2d(.5, .5));
    p.addPoint(.4, .8);
    p.addPoint(new Point2d(.2, .5));

    System.out.println(p);
}

 }
```

Comment: There is in important difference between your two add() methods. But most importantly, your points variable is useless. Just use the add() method taking a single argument. You could also avoid duplication by using `return add(new Point2d(x, y));` Also, what's the point of returning a boolean, which is always true, and which you ignore anyway, from these methods?

Comment: Good point. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not incrementing the position in your `addPoint(double x, double y)`, so basically, **you are replacing the existing point with a new point**, so you are missing few point values and you need to correct the correct the code as shown below:

```
public boolean addPoint(double x, double y) {
        Point2d a = new Point2d(x, y);
        p.add(points, a);
        points++;
        return true;
    }
```

**Because you are simply adding the point at the end of the list, I suggest you can directly use `arraylist.add(point);`** so that you will not get into these increment/other issues.

Also, **you can change your constructor of Polygon class (which accepts `int`) as follows because you are not using the `numPoints` variable** or else use an array with `numPoints` as the size instead of `ArrayList`.

```
public Polygon() {
    p = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Both of you guys answered it correctly Idk whom should I mark it right

Comment: Did you have a look at my other suggestions?

Comment: I'm looking at it

Comment: This is generic. For non-generic do I just remove < > ?

Comment: `<>` is diamond operator, you can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Answer (score 1):

You did not increment points in the addPoint(double x, double y) function.

Comment: Both of you guys answered it correctly Idk whom should I mark it right

Answer (score 0):

Why not reuse the same method? and call the overloaded function 
`public boolean addPoint(Point2d point);` instead of writing the same logic again and again.

```
public boolean addPoint(double x, double y) {
   Point2d a = new Point2d(x,y);
   return addPoint(a);
}
```