# Is there a reason to double parametrize generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, semantics

Is there any reason to do this:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

versus this:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
```

I've seen the first usage a few times, and it seems to provide no benefit, which begs the question: why use it?

I understand that the diamond operator (<>) is necessary to differentiate between `new LinkedList()` and `new LinkedList<>()`, just to be clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the point of the diamond operator in Java 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

Comment: Uh, what?  The diamond operator was added _after_ the other form, to let you do the `ArrayList<>` syntax instead of the longer form.  You've mixed up the historical ordering.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in not using `new ArrayList<>()`, unless the code compiles using a pre-1.7 compiler, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've seen the first usage a few times, and it seems to provide no
>   benefit, which begs the question: why use it?

`<>` operator has been introduced only in JDK1.7, so you might have seen a legacy code, which used `new ArrayList<Integer>()` (without `<>` operator)

Also, the support to the code (like `<Integer>`) without using `<>` operator still exists because of **backward compatibility**.

So, the answer is you will not use it if your project uses JDK1.7 or later.

Answer (score 0):

The first usage with the type redundantly stated was required before Java 7 when the type inferencing provided by the diamond syntax was introduced.