# how to instantiate Map<String, Map<String, JsonNode>>

Tags: java, dictionary, playframework, hashmap

Im getting compile error when I tried instantiating above method with this:

```
new HashMap<String, new HashMap<String, JsonNode>()>()
```

Thanks

[Please see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0RKY.png)

Comment: Why do you think you need to instantiate something for a generic type?

Comment: Please post the error message as text instead of a picture.

Comment: Im trying to run an unit test. Apparently, that is one of the field of the class im instantiating

Answer (score 2):

When you call the constructor, you can use [Diamond Inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7) to tell the compiler to "figure it out":

```
Map<String, Map<String, JsonNode>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

If you really want to declare the whole type, then it's similar to the variable declaration. You only use the parenthesizes when you call the constructor, not for each generic type:

```
Map<String, Map<String, JsonNode>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, JsonNode>>();
```