# Function argument and return value does look incorrect - Spring ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, httpentity

I have such problem with ResponseEntity. The function returns such statement:

```
public ResponseEntity<User>
```

And some functions doesn't return type User instead some thing:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

What do you think about above example?

Comment: What makes you think this is incorrect? Did you try and this does not work?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Comment: I think that return statement doesn't match with function's retured data type. Example is from the book. In my opinion there is no User instance in return Statement.Ex:
return new ResponseEntity<>(userSaved, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

Comment: What does mean and what the difference is between:

    ResponseEntity<User>
and

    ResponseEntity<>