# what's the differences between using <> and not using it in java?

Tags: java

I have a piece of code like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find/{id}")
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<QuestionModel> find(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Question question = questionService.find(id);
    QuestionModel questionModel = new QuestionModel(question);
    **return new ResponseEntity<>(questionModel, HttpStatus.OK);**
}
```

I wanna know that what's differences between that & this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find/{id}")
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<QuestionModel> find(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Question question = questionService.find(id);
    QuestionModel questionModel = new QuestionModel(question);
    **return new ResponseEntity(questionModel, HttpStatus.OK);**
}
```

Comment: If you don't use any `<...>` you will use **raw-types**. You should **never** use raw-types. Java only still supports it for backwards compatibility reasons with Java < 5. Using `<>` (diamond operator) instead of `<Foo>` (writing it out) is just syntax sugar for convenience. The compiler replaces the diamond operator with the fully-written out type.

Comment: The difference in the above code would be a warning at compile time in the latter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use any `<...>` you will use **raw-types**. You should **never** use raw-types, generics are way safer to use and prevent way more bugs due to increased compiler knowledge. Java only still supports it for backwards compatibility reasons *< Java 5*. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Using `<>` (diamond operator) instead of `<Foo>` (writing it out) is just syntactic sugar for convenience. The compiler replaces the diamond operator with the fully-written out type (same for `var` in *Java 10*). See [What is the point of the diamond operator in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)

```
// Are the same
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

// Raw types, don't use if > Java 5
List values = new ArrayList();
// Assigning a raw-type to a generic variable, mixing both, don't use
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList();
```