# Java Collection method to lambda method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, lambda, collections

how can i change this method to lambda without any loops or if's?

```
public Collection<String> test (Collection<String> strings) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayListOfStrings = new ArrayList();

    for(String str : strings) {
        if(str.length() >= 10) {
            String s = str.substring(str.length() / 2);
            if(s.charAt(0) >= 'a') {
                arrayListOfStrings.add(s.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayListOfStrings;
}
```

i've tried it this way, someones got another or better solution?:

```
public Collection<String> test (Collection<String> strings) {

    ArrayList<String> arrayListOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Stream<String> myStream = strings.stream()
            .filter(str -> str.length() >= 10)
            .map(str -> str.substring(str.length()/2))
            .filter(str -> str.charAt(0) >= 'a');

    myStream.forEach(str -> arrayListOfStrings.add(str.toUpperCase()));

    return arrayListOfStrings ;

}
```

thx for help :)

Comment: "without any loops, if's or iteration" -- you may not be fully clear on how streams work under the hood

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please make an **attempt**, instead of asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: `new ArrayList()` is a *raw* generic. Do not use *raw* generics. [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5221149) --- Use the diamond operator: `new ArrayList<>()`. [What is the point of the diamond operator (<>) in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166966/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) method using [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--):

```
public Collection<String> test(Collection<String> strings) {
    return strings.stream()
            .filter(str -> str.length() >= 10)
            .map(str -> str.substring(str.length() / 2))
            .filter(s -> s.charAt(0) >= 'a')
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Your question said:

> without any loops or if's

but you should be aware that `filter()` uses an `if` statement, and `collect()` uses a loop to iterate the elements of the stream, so you haven't eliminated "loops or if's", you've just delegated that logic to the stream framework.

Comment: thanks a lot! I should have described it better, the task was to remove the if's and loops only for this method

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution. likely slower but this is what you wanted.

```java
    public Collection<String> test2(Collection<String> strings, int minLength) {
        return strings.stream().filter(s -> s.length() >= minLength)
                .map(s -> s.substring(s.length() / 2))
                .filter(s -> s.charAt(0) >= 'a')
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: You missed the `toUpperCase()` part.

Comment: My bad, nice catch. Thanks.

Comment: Calling `toUpperCase()` before doing `s.charAt(0) >= 'a'` will yield different results, since all letters will now be excluded.