# Get two notes in Pair class in java while compiling code

Tags: java

I write code to clear the doubt about Pair class in java. I got my output what I expected but while compiling I got a note.

```
Note: MyArrayList.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

My Code is

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 
class MyArrayList
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Pair<String, Integer> p1 = new Pair("Shubham", 1804017);
    Pair<Integer, String> p2 = new Pair(1804025,"Sanket");
    Pair<Boolean, String> p3 = new Pair(true,"Sanket");

    p1.getInfo();
    p2.getInfo();
    p3.getInfo();
     }
}

class Pair<X,Y>
{
    X x;
    Y y;
    
    public Pair(X x,Y y)
      {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
      }
    public void getInfo()
       {
         System.out.println(x+" "+y);  
       }
}
```

So What is that note and can we avoid it?

Comment: Did you `Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked`? (Oddly, though, I would have expected a warning about raw types instead of unchecked.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the diamond operator here.

```
Pair<String, Integer> p1 = new Pair<>("Shubham", 1804017);
Pair<Integer, String> p2 = new Pair<>(1804025,"Sanket");
Pair<Boolean, String> p3 = new Pair<>(true,"Sanket");
```

See also [What is the point of the diamond operator (<>) in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7)