# Does Java assume type based on result?

Tags: java

There is a code in Java:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> langMap = new HashMap<>();
    langMap.put(1, "Java");
    langMap.put(2, "C#");
    Collection<String> values = langMap.values();
  }
}
```

In the last code line there is `Collection<String>`. Isn't `<String>` unnecessary because the type is assumed based on the values assigned from langMap?

Comment: "Unnecessary" in what sense? The type of `langMap.values()` is `Collection<String>` because that's the return type of the method.

Comment: Recent versions of Java can [infer local variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/local-variable-type-inference.html), if that's what you're asking about

Comment: @AndyTurner His question is why the declaration `Collection<String> values` requires `<String>` if it's implicitly known given the assigned `langMap.values()`. (I think ..)

Comment: @akuzminykh that would have been clearer with the backticks :)

Comment: @akuzminykh yes exactly

Comment: I believe Generic's Type Erasure concept is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) The `values()` method of an HashMap return `Collection<V>`.

V is a generics that will be inferred to the type of the value of the HashMap that you declared.

## `var` keyword

In Java 10 and later, you could use the `var` syntax to write :

`var values = langMap.values();`

…and the type of the `Collection` would be implicitly inferred. Here it would be inferred as `Collection<String>` since you declared the `Map` as `Map<Integer, **String**>`.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YOj48i).

See also [*JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

Answer (score 7):

> Isn't `<String>` unnecessary

No, it's necessary: without `<String>`, the type of the variable would be `Collection`, which is a *raw type*. [Don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

I suppose Java could have a notation for such contexts like `Collection<>`, similar to the [diamond notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166966/3788176), but it doesn't.

You either have to use `Collection<String>`, or `var` in language versions which support it (11 and higher).

Answer (score 1):

To say that it is unnecessary is not true, since  According to your code you are trying to get the Set(  Collection) of values from map .so to define the data type of this collection ( i.e data type of information that collection will be storing) will prevent any further error and makes it a clean. Otherwise, it might show a format exception.
for instance, take this example when you want to store a value of Map of name 'map'  containing the values of the integer data type.

// to get all the value of a map

Collection values = map.values();

// this convert your collection of values  into any further collection
// like ArrayList I have done here

ArrayList listOfValues = new ArrayList(values);

*****this line of code taken from my GitHub repo link is given down below
line 26 , 27 .
https://github.com/gulab786-SRG/Gfg_Solution/blob/master/gfg/Maximum%20_Width_of_Tree.java