# There is a method to dinamically change the size of array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner with java and I wanted to know if there was a way to dynamically instantiate an array, that is, being able to add and remove elements by changing the actual size of the array.

Comment: Arrays can be created with a size that can be calculated, but once it's created it has a fixed size. The answer from Klayser shows the class to use as alternative.

Comment: Once created, the size of an array cannot be changed. When you need more space, you need to create a bigger array and then copy all the values to the new one. Which is what ArrayList does internally so you don't have to deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java there is a class called Arraylist,
to import it `import java.util.ArrayList;`

you have to declare it with the data type you want it to contain an example below with some strings

```
ArrayList <String> cars = new ArrayList <String> ();
```

To add an item just use the .add (item) function like this

```
cars.add ("Tesla");
```

to remove instead it is necessary to have the index and with the command `.remove (index)`
you can remove an object

```
cars.remove(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Arraylist: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This snippet will not compile; the class is called `ArrayList` (note the capitalization). Additionally, you should specify the generic type or use [the diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166966) in modern Java code. The snippet then becomes `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`.