# I keep on encountering error, I can't find the common elements in array

Tags: java, arrays

> Let the user input string in array then find the common elements

I keep on encountering error, I can't find the common elements in array.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class number2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Enter First countries: ");
        Scanner Country1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = Country1.nextLine();
        l.add(a);

        List<String> m = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Enter Second Countries: ");
        Scanner Country2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b = Country2.nextLine();
        m.add(b);

        System.out.println("First countries: " + l);
        System.out.println("Second Countries: " + m);

        System.out.println("Common country/s: " + l.retainAll(m));
    }
}
```

The user is supposed to enter a list of countries, for example:

> japan,korea,china

And same for second list, for example:

> korea,chile,mexico

The output is `[]` (an empty array) when it should be `[korea]`.

Comment: Whats your input? What is the expected output?

Comment: the expected output is anything that the two input array have in common

Comment: You're only adding one string in each list. Are you typing multiple countries into one input?  Maybe you want to split the string? idk

Comment: for example: Coutry1{"japan, korea, china"} country2:{korea, chile, maxico"}  so...  the output is Common country/s: korea

Comment: yes, paul i am trying to type multiplecountries in input

Comment: You need to split the string

Comment: If you input multiple countries you need to split the string, not treat it as a single string, because then obviously you don't have "japan", "korea" and "china" but "japan, korea, china".

Comment: how can i split the string can you please help me?

Comment: If you read the Java documentation you'll find the String class has a method to split it

Comment: also i have a problem on how to find the common element after the user input the data

Comment: I'd recommend first getting your input correctly split and stored in the lists, and then you can worry about finding the common elements if what you already have doesn't work

Comment: i have already split this ;)

Comment: next problem is getting the common element

Comment: I'm pretty sure that creating the algorithm for finding the common elements and implementing it are the assignment.  If you are struggling, you should contact your TA/instructor for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Notes after the code.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class number2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter first countries separated by comma: ");
        String a = stdin.nextLine();
        String[] countries1 = a.split(",");
        l.addAll(Arrays.asList(countries1));

        List<String> m = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter second countries separated by comma: ");
        String b = stdin.nextLine();
        String[] countries2 = b.split(",");
        m.addAll(Arrays.asList(countries2));

        System.out.println("First countries: " + l);
        System.out.println("Second Countries: " + m);
        l.retainAll(m);
        System.out.println("Common country/s: " + l);
    }
}
```

- You don't need to create a new [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) each time you want to get input from the user. The above code creates a single `Scanner` and assigns it to variable `stdin`.
- When assigning a value to variables `l` and `m`, you should use the [diamond operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java).
- You say that the user is supposed to enter a list of countries separated by commas. Hence, in order to get a `List`, you need to call method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), of class `java.lang.String`, on the user-entered string and then create a `List` by calling method [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)), of interface `java.util.List` since method `split` returns an array. You need to do this for both lists of countries that the user enters. Note that in the above code, the countries **must** be separated by a single comma without spaces. If you want a different delimiter you need to change the argument to method `split`. The argument is a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).
- Finally you can call method [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)). However that method returns `boolean` and modifies the `List`. So after the method call, i.e. `l.retainAll(m)`, `l` will contain only the common countries.

Here is output from a sample run.

```
Enter first countries separated by comma: 
japan,korea,china
Enter second countries separated by comma: 
korea,chile,mexico
First countries: [japan, korea, china]
Second Countries: [korea, chile, mexico]
Common country/s: [korea]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the entries into your arrayList  `l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a.split(" ")));` :

For the common list you can use this :

```
    //edit to list the common element using stream 
    l = l.stream().filter(m::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //or this one
    //--- l.retainAll(m);
    System.out.println("Common country/s: "+l);
```

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> l=new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter First countries: ");
    Scanner Country1=new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = Country1.nextLine();
    l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a.split(" ")));

    List<String> m=new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Countries: ");
    Scanner Country2=new Scanner(System.in);
    String b = Country2.nextLine();
    m = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b.split(" ")));

    System.out.println("First countries: "+l);
    System.out.println("Second Countries: "+m);

    //edit to list the common element using stream 
    l = l.stream().filter(m::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //or this one
    //--- l.retainAll(m);

    System.out.println("Common country/s: "+l);

}
```

**Output :**

```
Enter First countries: 
korea japan china
Enter Second Countries: 
japan china usa
First countries: [korea, japan, china]
Second Countries: [japan, china, usa]
Common country/s: [japan, china]
```

Comment: thank you i almost there, but what about the common element it only says true? it has to be Korea and japan since they are the common element

Comment: @jipyeong see the edit and the outputs