# Why does vavr's Try container catches Throwable but not Exception?

Tags: java, exception, vavr

I'm not an expert in java's type system and exception handling.
But i found in SO that we should only catch exceptions but not throwable's.

Here is the link:
[Difference between using Throwable and Exception in a try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274102/difference-between-using-throwable-and-exception-in-a-try-catch)

In Vavr's library i found this source code:

```java
public interface Try<T> extends Value<T>, Serializable {
    long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static <T> Try<T> of(CheckedFunction0<? extends T> supplier) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(supplier, "supplier is null");

        try {
            return new Try.Success(supplier.apply());
        } catch (Throwable var2) {
            return new Try.Failure(var2);
        }
    }
}
```

Would i have any issues in future if i will use this container? Will i miss some critical exceptions that may occur during execution of 'of' function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `Throwable` was used instead of `Exception`, is because we want our `Try` objects to also catch `Error`s. This his how the inheritance model of `Exceptions` and `Errors` looks like:

[image]

If we only catch `Exceptions`, an [`IOError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOError.html) would crash our code and prevent us from using the strength of a `Try` chain:

```java
Try.of(() -> throw new IOError(null))
  .onFailure(() -> /* Do something to fix the IOError */);
```

When catching `Throwable`, this `IOError` will be caught, and we will be able to execute the `onFailure` method. If we only catch `Exception`, the execution would have stopped on line one, and the `onFailure` would never be executed.

Answer (score 5):

`Throwable` is a superclass of `Exception`, meaning `catch (Throwable var)` catches Exceptions as well. Therefore the code in vavr is correct - whenever there is any `Throwable` thrown it will be wrapped in a `Try.Failure`.

Answer (score 5):

Note what the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274116/3000206) in the linked post says:

> You should generally not do that, except perhaps at the very highest "catch all" level of a thread where you want to log or **otherwise handle absolutely everything that can go wrong**.

Emphasis mine.

That is likely the intent here. This is a `try` wrapper meant to handle *everything* and let the user decide what they want to deal with and how. It seems they're going for a construct like Scala's [`Try`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html) to let you handle exceptions without manually catching them. For that to work and be consistent, *everything* should be handled the same way, or you'd have some exceptions needing to be caught, and others that are handled as this class intends.

As for

> Will i miss some critical exceptions that may occur during execution of 'of' function?

You won't miss them. They're be returned wrapped in a `Try.Failure`, and you can handle them then after receiving the error.