# PHP try catch inside a function not working. Why?

Tags: php, exception

I try to catch exception inside a function, but it is not working.

```
function dbquery ($mysqli, $query){
  try {
    $result = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $query);
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught exception: ".$e->getMessage();                        
    $result = false;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

The exception is not caught in the function and an uncaught `mysqli_sql_exception` is thrown when the function is called. What am I doing wrong? I don't believe I have to make a try block around every function call.

Comment: Where is the mysqli_sql_exception thrown? Can you show the full message?

Comment: It is crazy. If the function is declared in the main php file where it is also later called, then the exception is caught properly. If the function is declared in another php file which is required in the main file, then the exception is not caught. However if I changed Exception to Throwable, then the exception is caught. Anybody here able to explain why?

Comment: Can you answer my questions?

Comment: Here is the full message: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in /home/www/objkal.cz/www/objkal.cz/confcom.php:251 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/objkal.cz/www/objkal.cz/confcom.php(251): mysqli_query() #1 /home/www/objkal.cz/www/objkal.cz/_try_catch_test.php(44): dbquery() #2 {main} thrown in /home/www/objkal.cz/www/objkal.cz/confcom.php on line 251

Comment: The message tells us that this is a **fatal error** which is not an exception. The reason why you didn't get an exception has been mentioned by Marcel, you need to manually specify `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`, the flag is set by default since PHP 8.1 btw.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right. I think fatal error is that the mysqli_sql_exception was not caught. If the function dbquery() is defined in the same php file were the function is later called then exception is caught properly and no error occures.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to catch all Error could there be with the `Exception $e`. Try `Throwable $e` to catch all types of Error.

For more information, please refer to this question (it's not PHP question but it's a similar problem):
[Difference between using Throwable and Exception in a try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274102/difference-between-using-throwable-and-exception-in-a-try-catch)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the official documentation is right the thrown `mysqli_sql_exception` inherits from `RuntimeException` and should be catched then, because `RuntimeException` extends from `Exception`.

You could at least try to catch a `Throwable` in combination with the right mysqli error reporting.

`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Yes, change to Throwable helped. However no Idea why? Exception is thrown not an Error.