# Custom Exception class - extends from Exception or Thowable?

Tags: java, exception

I am designing a custom Exception class for my application. I have a very basic question. Should I extend from **Exception class** or **Thowable class** ? What are the benefits ?

I intend to throw this from underlying layers and catch it in the top level classes. Will it influence my decision of using Thowable over Exception.  Is it fundamentally right to catch a Thowable ?

I 've gone through some other threads in this forum. They talk about having the stack trace maintained when it is thrown and not having it for exception etc.
I understand that some say ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498217/when-should-throwable-be-used-instead-of-new-exception)) that Thowable is super class of Exception and we should not use it. But others ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129647/exception-vs-throwable-in-java)) say Exception is for "Exceptional " cases.

This question is rather a discussion of how one is better than other rather than asking how.

Comment: In the end, what you are going to catch at the top level is `YourException` - whether it is an Exception or a Throwable does not make much difference. If others might use your API and have to catch that Exception, extending Exception would probably create less surprise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yea, I agree with it. I was just making sure my decision is right. I don't want any pne picking on me. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Throwable` is a class for all the bad situations, which can arise: Errors & Exceptions.

`Error` is something, you **can't handle at all**: `OutOfMemoryError`, `VirtualMachineError`, etc.

`Exception` is for **exceptional cases**.

*Exceptions* come in 2 flavours:

1. `RuntimeException`s.

   These ones, you are *not aware of*: `NullPointerException`, `ClassCastException`, etc.
2. `Checked` exceptions.

   These are the exceptions, which your code *is aware of* and should be explicitely catched (`... throws MyException`): `IOException`s, etc.

If you want the users of your code, to explicitely handle some exceptional situations, it would be good to just extend `Exception`, not the `RuntimeException`. There's no need to extend `Throwable`.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally you should extends `Exception` class as you are creating `Custom Exception`. `Exception` and `Error` both extends `Throwable`, It really does not make sense extending `Throwable`.

Answer (score 4):

`Throwable` is the super class of `Error` & `Exception`.

Like `Exception`, `Error` too, can be thrown & handled.

But it is not advisable, according to the following doc:

> You are not required to catch Error objects or Error subtypes. You can
>   also throw an Error yourself (although other than AssertionError you
>   probably won't ever want to), and you can catch one, but again, you
>   probably won't. What, for example, would you actually do if you got an
>   OutOfMemoryError?

Keeping this concept in mind, I would suggest to extend `Throwable` if you want to throw and/or catch `Exception` & `Error` both. Extend `Exception` if you want to throw and/or catch `Exception` only.