# What is the built in base class to handle all exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, throwable

What is the built in base class to handle all exceptions in Java?
Is It Exception or Throwable?

What is the difference between two builtin classes,can someone explain me.

Comment: Read the documentation of Error and compare it with that of Exception, both throwables but with different meanings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129647/exception-vs-throwable-in-java

check this out. This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below image will help you to understand `Exception` Hierarchy

[image]

Image Ref: [programcreek:](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/diagram-for-hierarchy-of-exception-classes/)

As you can see `Throwable` is super class of [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) and [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) while `Exception` deals with checked and unchecked Exception.

[Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

> [The term exception is shorthand for the phrase "exceptional event."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

[Throwable:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

> The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language. Only objects that are instances of this class (or one of its subclasses) are thrown by the Java Virtual Machine or can be thrown by the Java throw statement. Similarly, only this class or one of its subclasses can be the argument type in a catch clause. For the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions, Throwable and any subclass of Throwable that is not also a subclass of either RuntimeException or Error are regarded as checked exceptions.

Comment: where did you get this picture from?

Comment: I know google but if you paste information here it is always a good idea to mention the source. First for credits and second for the reference of the readers. They may want to know the source of your claim so they can trust it and dig deeper into that resource if they are interested. Compare the other answers you say "from the javadocs..."

Comment: @chiccodoro accepted sir. will follow from next time. thanks.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from editing your answer and adding a URL. BTW I like your answer. I've just kept my upvote for the moment the reference slips in ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The javadocs are for this. Here you can see that [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) is the superclass for all `Exceptions` and `Errors`. Then you have checked and unchecked `Exceptions`, where the latter is `RuntimeException` and all its subclasses.

Remember to use Google when you're wondering about things like this, because all this information is widely available and easily found with a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html):

### Class Exception

```
java.lang.Object
 |
 ->java.lang.Throwable
    |
    ->java.lang.Exception
```

Hope this clears the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The above answered are very much informative. I just want to add:

- The Master Base Class:
  `java.lang.Object`
- The Master Exception Class:
  `java.lang.Throwable`
- The Master Exception Class extends `Throwable`:
  `java.lang.Exception` and `java.lang.Error`
- The Unchecked class extends `Exception` extends `Throwable`:
  `java.lang.RuntimeException`