# Unable to instantiate java class of an External jar

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not able to instantiate `Tidy` as

```
Tidy t= new Tidy();
```

in my java code.

This jar is in my class path, and there are no compilation errors.

My code exits to the finally block after hitting this line without getting into the catch block, skipping any code after the line.

Comment: What error or exception do you get? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: If no exception is caught, it might be a Throwable: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129647/exception-vs-throwable-in-java

Comment: Like I mentioned, It jumps to the finally block...There is no exception

Comment: Can you show the code block in question? Then this question will be much easier to answer (e.g. what's in the `try` block after the line in question, what is `Tidy` - your own class, a class from a framework etc?)

Comment: Probably that means you're catching the wrong thing in your catch block.  Catch Throwable (temporarily) to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from "Ray Hidayat" from this [StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498217/when-should-throwable-be-used-instead-of-new-exception).

> Throwable is the superclass to Exception and Error, so you would catch
>   Throwable if you wanted to not only catch Exceptions but Errors,
>   that's the point in having it. The thing is, Errors are generally
>   things which a normal application wouldn't and shouldn't catch, so
>   just use Exception unless you have a specific reason to use Throwable.

I'm guessing an Error might be being thrown in your case. Try catching `Throwable` just to check, but as mentioned in the quote you shouldn't really catch Throwable.

Comment: It was a Throwable. Turns out, there was a mismatch between my build time class path and run time class path, It worked after adding the jTidy jar to my runtime classpath.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to add a `catch` for `Throwable` before the `finally` block, and try again to see if your code throws another exception.

```
try {
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally { ... }
}
```