# Why does this code sometimes throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, hashmap

Consider the following Java source:

```
if( agents != null ) {
  for( Iterator iter = agents.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    // Code that uses iter.next() ...
    //
  }
}
```

The `agents` is a `HashMap`.

Why does the `for` statement sometimes throw a `NullPointerException`?

Thank you.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Thread Safety**

If your code is multi-threaded, then it is possible. For example:

```
public class C {
  private Hashtable agents = new Hashtable();

  public iterate() {
    if( agents != null ) {
      for (Iterator iter = agents.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        // Code goes here
      }
    }
}
```

If another thread sets `agents` to `null` immediately after the `if` statement executes (but before the `for` loop), then you will get a `NullPointerException`. Avoid this by using accessors (combined with lazy initialization).

Also, as others have mentioned, avoid such looping constructs in favour of generics, if possible. See other answers for details.

**Accessors offer Protection**

If you always use the following pattern you will never have `NullPointerException`s in your source code (third-party code, on the other hand, might have issues that cause your code to fail, indirectly, which cannot be easily avoided).

```
public class C {
  private Hashtable agents;

  private synchronized Hashtable getAgents() {
    if( this.agents == null ) {
      this.agents = new Hashtable();
    }

    return this.agents;
  }

  public iterate() {
    Hashtable agents = getAgents();

    for (Iterator iter = agents.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
      // Code goes here
    }
  }
}
```

The code that iterates over the agents no longer needs to check for `null`. This code is much more robost for many reasons. You can substitute `Hashmap` (or any other abstract data type, such as `ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>`) for `Hashtable`.

**Open-Closed Principle**

If you were feeling especially generous with your time you could go as far as:

```
public class C {
  private Hashtable agents;

  private synchronized Hashtable getAgents() {
    if( this.agents == null ) {
      this.agents = createAgents();
    }

    return this.agents;
  }

  public iterate() {
    Iterator i = getAgentKeyIterator();

    while( i.hasNext() ) {
      // Code that uses i.next() ...
    }
  }

  protected Hashtable createAgents() {
    return new Hashtable();
  }

  private Iterator getAgentKeyIterator() {
    return getAgentKeys().iterator();
  }

  private KeySet getAgentKeys() {
    return getAgents().keySet();
  }
}
```

This would allow subclasses (written by other developers) to substitute their own subclass of the abstract data type being used (allowing the system greater flexibility in keeping with the [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)), without having to modify (or copy/waste) your original work.

Comment: I would think a `ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>` would be preferable to a `Hashtable`.

Comment: I think the multi threaded environment might explanation is plausible, let me poke around more on it, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't that be a while loop?

```
if (agents != null) {
    Iterator iter = agents.keyset().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        //some stuffs here
    }
}
```

or a for each?

```
if (agents != null) {
    //Assuming the key is a String
    for (String key : agents.keyset()) {
        //some stuffs here
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that a for loop is more appropriate for an Iterator. I would not use a while loop because the Iterator is then visible to all code after the while.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: Personally, I like the for each style loop the best, and use it instead of dealing with `Iterator`s directly.

Comment: Agreed, for each is better then using the Iterator directly (unless you need to call Iterator.remove()).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't set the `iter` to null inside the loop.