# Unreachable statement when using return in finally?

Tags: java

This compiles:

```
class Ex1 {
    public int show() {
        try {
            int a=10/10;
            return 10;
        }   
        catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
        }
        System.out.println("hello");
        return 20;
    }
}
```

on the other hand this doesn't:

```
class Ex15 {
    public int show() {
        try {
            int a=10/0;
            return 10;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
            return 40;
        }

        System.out.println("hello");
        return 20;
    }
}
```

and gives unreachable statement  System.out.println("hello"); error. why is it so?

Comment: please put your code in <code></code> block, it's really hard to read

Comment: What error do you get from the compiler? Just a warning that 10/0 is not a good idea?

Comment: Probably a warning about unreachable code block because of the return in the finally.

Comment: Please show us the compiler error, or it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Yes, but what makes return in finally do this?

Comment: Also it's helpful to add what the compiler says.

Comment: @Frustrated - In Java, this is a compile-time error.

Comment: @pablochan: Just add 4 spaces to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Why is this question community wiki?

Comment: @Taylor what is this community wiki?

Comment: @Taylor: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741

Comment: @Pyrolistical: This new title makes it sound like OP already knows the answer to this question. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The finally has a return so you are probably getting an unreachable code block error.

```
finally
{   
    System.out.println("Finally"); 
    return 40;
}
System.out.println("hello"); // unreachable code
return 20;
```

This is actually a compile-time  error in Java. See section [14.20](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html).

> It is a compile-time error if a
>   statement cannot be executed because
>   it is unreachable.

Comment: Is that an error by default? I think I was able to change that to a warning in Eclipse.

Comment: why only when finally's return is an error and not previously

Comment: It's a compiler error. I don't see how you could configure Eclipse to suppress it.

Comment: @Abson - Every execution path will make it to the finally and return. There is no way the code that prints "hello" will execute. Java treats this as a compiler error. The first example works fine because there is no return in the finally block.

Comment: L: Eclipse has an option for "dead code" but I'm not sure it's the same thing (might check later today).

Answer (score 7):

It's `unreachable code`. According to the compiler, `System.out.println("hello");` can never be executed.

Beside that, DON'T EVER write `return` within a `finally` block. (see [Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java/64618#64618) for why you should not).

EDIT:

> Yes, but what makes return in finally
>   do this?

It's not because it is in a finally block or something. Even if you'd remove the finally keyword, you will still get the error.

```
   class ex15 {
        public int show() {
            int a = 10 / 0;
            return 40;
            System.out.println("hello");
            return 20;
        }
    }
```

Obviously, if you `return 40`, there is no way you can execute the next line. `finally` just means "do always, no matter what". So.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a "return" in the "finally" block, anything that comes after it will never be executed.  The "return" statement ends the method right there.

You would get the same error if you put a System.out.println() in the first method, after the "return" statement in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return` in the `finally` block. This makes any statements after that unreachable. Also you have a `return` in the `try` block and again in the `finally` block. This doesn't make sense.