# Java stuff you didn't know you didn't know

Tags: java, language-features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java)

What are some Java language features or Java related tools that you were embarrassed to find that you didn't know about?  Examples for me are:

jmap

RuntimeException

Please post things every Java programmer should know about, be they language features, tools, or facts about how the JVM works, but that you found out about long after you should have.

Comment: You should make this Community Wiki, or you'll find it closed quite quickly...