# Static Variable Unwanted

Tags: java, eclipse, static

A very simple question for the experts, but for a beginner like me, it is just confusing.  I thought I understood Static, but apparently I do not.  This below is the entire class, and it says I need to make test static.  But I don't want to.  What can I do to fix this, and why is it happening in the first place?  Thanks!

```
public class SubstringTest
{
    private String test;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test = "Penguin";
        System.out.println(test);
        System.out.println(test.substring(3));

    }

}
```

Comment: private static String test;

Comment: main is a static method,. And you can access only static members inside a static method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why main method is static in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181207/why-main-method-is-static-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522026/public-static-void-main-access-non-static-variable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`main` is static. `test` is not.

If you don't want to make `test` static, you have to create an *instance* of `SubstringTest` first.

```
SubstringTest st = new SubstringTest(); // create an instance
st.test = "test"; // this works
System.out.println(st.test); // also works
```

If `test` is static, you can do

```
SubstringTest.test = "test";
```

Or if the code you're writing is in the class `SubstringTest` **and** `test` is static:

```
test = "test";
```

Comment: instance of SubstringTest?

Comment: gotcha thanks doorknob!  thats the part i understood about static which is why i was confused. now it makes sense!

Comment: i am in the class and did test = "test" but thats where the static error came from

Answer (score 5):

A static method cannot access non-static/instance variables, because a static method is never associated with any instance. A static method can’t directly invoke a non-static variable. But static method can access non-static variable by means of declaring instances and using them.

```
public class SubstringTest
{
private String test; // make it private static String test;

public static void main(String[] args)
{   // SubstringTest t = new SubstringTest(); Or change here.
    // t.test ="Penguin";
    test = "Penguin";
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(test.substring(3));

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You **CANNOT** access instance variables from a Static method.

Because a static method is called on a class instance and not to an object of a class. This means, that a static method is not able to access instance variables, because they are only instantiated in an object