# Java data types

Tags: java

I am inquiring about data types in Java.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        string x = "String variable";

        int y = 4;

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);      
    }
}
```

Why do I receive an error when I declare a `string` variable as all lowercase? I can declare `integers` and other data types all lowercase, but when I declare a `string` variable I must capitalize the "s" in "string"?

Comment: EDIT: I know a integer variable is declared by int... not integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is a primitive type. `String` is class. By convention, Java class names start with an uppercase. Primitive types are all lowercase (there are only a few primitive types defined in Java). It's just the way types are named.

Comment: Why is one a class though? Are they not both data types? I don't understand how a string variable must be a "class" and not a data type....

Comment: Both `int` and `String` are data types. But one is a _primitive_ data type, and the other is a _reference_ data type (e.g. a class or interface). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790809/whats-the-difference-between-primitive-and-reference-types and the Java tutorials.

Comment: @RobertTossly This might helpful   [how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using "";](:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410)

Comment: I will be looking into these now.

Answer (score 2):

Because Java is case sensitive and the class is `String`, not `string`.

Try `Int y = 4;`, that won't work either.

Primitive data types like `int` all start with lowercase, `String` isn't a primitive data type and thus is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

`integer` in java is not a keyword nor a class name.

`string` neither.

`Integer` is a class name (wrapper class for integer variable).

`int` is a keyword (indicates an integer primitive data type).

`String` is a class name.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: a primitive type is predefined by the language and is named by a reserved keyword. Primitive values do not share state with other primitive values. 
  The String class is not technically a primitive data type, it is included Java API (You can read a little more about it, always useful!).
  So, the biggest difference between int and String, is only that one is a Java Class, and the other is not.

this is a list of all the primitives in Java (all in lower case):

Numeric primitives: `short, int, long, float & double.`
Textual primitives: `byte and char.`
Boolean and null primitives: `boolean and null.`

For the Java Api Classes, you can check this other post ->

[Most-interest-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327451/most-interesting-useful-java-classes)

Finally, you can see another difference, I remember this one:

If you want a list of ints, you MUST type the list like this:

```
List<Integer> myInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myInts.add(1);
myInts.add(2);.......
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a predefined class, and it is a common programming style to make the first letter of a class in uppercase only. And all primitive datatypes (like `short,char,int,byte,float,double,long,boolean`) programming style is to make first letter as small. It is default in java