# In Java, is there a way to specify that an argument implements two interfaces

Tags: java

I am tempted to do such kind of code, using jGraphT

```
/*
  interface DirectedGraph<V,E> { ...}
  interface WeightedGraph<V,E> { ...}
*/

public class SteinerTreeCalc  {

    public SteinerTreeCalc( < ??? implements DirectedGraph<V,E>, WeightedGraph<V,E> > graph )  {
     ......
    }


}
```

I want to create a constructor that ask for an object implementing two interfaces.

**Update :**

In my goal, there are already chosen classes for Vertex and Edges (V and E), but thanks a lot to people who come up with  :

```
public class SteinerTreeCalc <V, E, T extends DirectedGraph<V, E> & WeightedGraph<V, E>>  
{ 
   ....
}
```

Comment: I assume you have a good reason for not naming the interface that is both a `DirectedGraph` and a `WeightedGraph`, so that you can get all the bits of the contract that the user of the `SteinerTreeCalc` is required to support in one place?

Comment: A good one ! JgraphT doesn't provide such interface that is both a DirectedGraph and a WeightedGraph, and the user might not want to use my custom interface/classes. I don't really understand why they didn't provide this interface.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
public class SteinerTreeCalc<T extends DirectedGraph<V,E> & WeightedGraph<V,E>> {
  public SteinerTreeCalc(T graph) {
    ......
  }
}
```

Comment: What's V and E? Shouldn't it be SteinerTreeCalc<V,E,T extends DirectedGraph<V,E> & WeightedGraph<V,E>>

Comment: I assume it's some inner class, where `V` and `E` are known. It's absent also in original question.

Comment: This makes the class generic though.

Answer (score 9):

Should work like this, but this is complexer generics logic, hope you can adapt:

```
public static interface DirectedGraph<V, E> {
}

public static interface WeightedGraph<V, E> {
}

public <V, E, T extends DirectedGraph<V, E> & WeightedGraph<V, E>> SteinerTreeCalc(T bothInterfaces) {
    // do it
}
```

These are the interfaces and the constructor like asked in your question.

Comment: +1: Very similar to what I was coding. However, wouldn't `V` and `E` reside on the class itself and not on the constructor? I suppose it depends on the author's goals.

Answer (score 6):

This could be what you want:
[Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java/42686#42686)

Comment: Yes it is. I will take a deeper look to hidden features ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use **extends** instead of **implements** in above code

Answer (score 0):

If `V` and `E` are concrete classes rather than type parameters, then you could create a new interface as follows:

```
public interface DirectedWeightedGraph extends 
    DirectedGraph<V,E>, WeightedGraph<V,E> {
}
```

then

```
public class SteinerTreeCalc  {

    public SteinerTreeCalc(DirectedWeightedGraph graph)  {
       ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the actual argument *must* implement the `DirectedWeightedGraph` interface.  A type that just implements `DirectedGraph<V,E>` and `WeightedGraph<V,E>` is not sufficient.