# Hidden Features of Java - ArrayList / instance initializers clarification

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

In the [Hidden Features of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java) question, I was interested in [the answer about instance initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java/47493#47493).

I was wondering how to modify this line :

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{ add(1); add(2); }};
```

in order to make it perform the same job with nested Arraylists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = ...
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{ add(1); add(2); }};
```

I don't really recommend this approach, as it creates an (anonymous) class for no good reason.

Use either:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
```

or

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
```

For 2 levels, you can use:

```
List<List<Integer>> numbers = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(2,3,4));
```

With a static import you could even reduce it to this, if you really want to:

```
List<List<Integer>> numbers = asList(asList(1, 2), asList(2,3,4));
```

Answer (score 3):

Double-brace initialization got a lot less interesting for lists now that Arrays.asList takes varargs,  you can do this instead:

```
List<List<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
numbers.add(Arrays.asList(1,2));
numbers.add(Arrays.asList(3,4));
```

Or combine with double-brace initialization like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>() {{add(Arrays.asList(1,2)); add(Arrays.asList(3,4));}};
```

but whether it fits on one line depends on your project's code-formatting guidelines. This is so horribly verbose that alternatives start to look good. Like putting the numbers into a string and parsing it. Or switching to Scala, Groovy, or Clojure, all of whom support literal list syntax.

Comment: Double-brace initialization may still be useful for map initialization, although e.g. Guava has factory methods for small maps.

Comment: thanks all for the answer..i was wondering if there is a way to condense the code you showed us, in order put the do add method calls in the first line. Something like : List<List<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(){add(Arrays.asList(1,2)),add(Arrays.asList(3,4))};
is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

And of course you can do the same for the inner ArrayLists:, though I think it becomes pretty unreadable...

```
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()
    {
        {
            add(new ArrayList<Integer>()
            {
                {
                    add(1);
                    add(2);
                }
            });
            add(new ArrayList<Integer>()
            {
                {
                    add(1);
                    add(2);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

though not wildly longer or worse than the conventional way (depending on your brace style!)

```
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(2);
    numbers.add(list1);
    numbers.add(list2);
```

The Arrays.asList(1, 2) approach given in other answers seems nicest of all.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use this idiom to "simplify" `ArrayList` declarations. It looks cool, but it needlessly creates an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList`, and it looks too "magical" for my tastes... You want code that is both readable and understandable by the next developer.

You should instead consider using a library such as [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Here is an example using Guava's [Lists.newArrayList(E... elements)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28E...%29) utility method:

```
    import com.google.common.collect.Lists;


    List<ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = Lists.newArrayList(
            Lists.newArrayList(1, 2),
            Lists.newArrayList(3, 4)
    );
```

Or, even better, using only the `List` interface on the left-hand side (you should avoid using concrete classes in your variable declarations):

```
    import com.google.common.collect.Lists;


    List<List<Integer>> numbers = Lists.<List<Integer>>newArrayList(
            Lists.newArrayList(1, 2),
            Lists.newArrayList(3, 4)
    );
```

If you know these lists will be immutable, it's even better to use [ImmutableList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html):

```
    import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;


    List<List<Integer>> numbers = ImmutableList.<List<Integer>>of(
            ImmutableList.of(1, 2),
            ImmutableList.of(3, 4)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `int` with object of `ArrayList<integer>`

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>() {

            {
                add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            }
        };
```