# How do I programmatically refresh a view page with AJAX?

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, view

I wrote a custom link in my page which created by views module, I want to click it to do something, then the page will refresh by ajax, how do I implement this?

I am sorry I didn't express myself clearly, I use Drupal 7, and  the  Views module to custom my own page.

Comment: You don't, you refersh the page using JavaScript. AJAX is a technique, not a language.

Comment: Which javascript library are you using? What do you mean by "view"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden Features of Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/views_refresh or just use the code below in your JS to refresh the view.

```
$('.view-dom-id-403402eee35f68cd32fe87b45702dc63').triggerHandler('RefreshView');
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event to the link, and when that is fired, execute an AJAX request.