# Database agnostic query to get the row number based on the primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

Let `country` be a table in an RDBMS system. Its columns are intuitive. Therefore, I do not go in depth nor they are required to know.

I needed SQL statements like the following at many places through out the application while using JPA (through EclipseLink / Hibernate).

MySQL :

```sql
SELECT rownum 
FROM   (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, tbl.country_id 
        FROM   country tbl, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t 
        ORDER  BY tbl.country_id DESC)t 
WHERE  country_id =?
```

Oracle (using window analytic functions) :

```sql
SELECT row_num 
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (ORDER BY country_id DESC) AS row_num, country_id 
        FROM   country 
        ORDER  BY country_id DESC) 
WHERE  country_id = ?
```

This native statement is required to be executed directly through the use of the `createNativeQuery()` method as follows.

```java
entityManager.createNativeQuery("Above Query")
             .setParameter(1, id)
             .getResultList();
```

These statements are meant to return a row number based on the given primary key value as set by using the `setParameter()` method.

They are not database agnostic. Does there exist any database agnostic stuff in JPA?

<sub>I do not use the `getSingleResult()` method to get a single (scalar) value as this method would unnecessarily throw an exception, if a query statement returned none or multiple rows accidently.</sub>

Comment: I do not really understand your question. What do you want to achieve? The row number in any DBMS is a very tricky thing. Most DBMS will count row numbers starting at 1 for each new result set (which could be a join as well).
I recommend not relying on row numbers. Especially not if you want to support different DBMS.

Comment: A row number is needed in situations, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1804983) link, if clicked, directly points to an answer available in the **fourth page**. When a user passes an `id` (primary key value) by clicking a link, the row is required to be highlighted which is possible only if the row number corresponding to that row is returned - same as that SO answer is highlighted by **automatically selecting the corresponding page**.

Comment: Starting from MySQL 8, you don't need a special syntax anymore. It supports window functions now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL and HQL are using a simplified querying syntax that dates back to [SQL-92](http://vladmihalcea.com/time-to-break-free-from-the-sql-92-mindset/). That's because most databases are SQL-92 compliant.

So you can't emulate these queries with HQL or JPQL, meaning you have to use native queries.

To hide the database specific details you can define your queries as $db_query_name and then simply supply the $db at runtime.

Comment: What is `$db_query_name`? Is it something special? Thank you.

Comment: It's just a naming convention I came up with. $db would be 'oracle' or 'mysql' while query_name the actual query name.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MySQL 8, you don't need a special syntax for MySQL anymore as it now supports window functions. However, if it didn't your *particular* query can always be rewritten in a SQL-92 fashion without window functions easily:

**If you already *know* that your `country_id` parameter exists**

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM country WHERE country_id >= ?
```

**If you don't know whether your `country_id` parameter exists**

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM country
WHERE country_id >= ?
AND ? IN (SELECT country_id FROM country)
```

The translation isn't entirely correct if `country_id` isn't unique (I'm assuming it is). If it isn't, then this corresponds to `RANK()`, not `ROW_NUMBER()`.