# Checked exception is not thrown and turned into RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception

What is happening here?

Why checked child of IOException (RemoteException) gets converted to RuntimeException?

Snippet taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496/hidden-features-of-java?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

class Thrower {
    public static void spit(final Throwable exception) {
        class EvilThrower<T extends Throwable> {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            private void sneakyThrow(Throwable exception) throws T {
                throw (T) exception; // something interesting 
            }
        }
        new EvilThrower<RuntimeException>().sneakyThrow(exception);
    }
}

public class ThrowerSample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Thrower.spit(new RemoteException("go unchecked!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: because `RuntimeException` ?

Comment: It's not converted to a runtime exception. The compiler is just tricked, by using unchecked generic casts, to think that the checked exception is a runtime exception.

Comment: In general, a cast doesn't change anything (except primitive types). It just adds runtime checks (which in this case, pass).

Comment: Checked exceptions are a purely compile-time concept. At runtime, they are exactly the same as unchecked exceptions. You are entirely dependent upon the compiler to determine whether there is anything that needs to be handled.

Comment: @RealSkeptic in this case, the cast does *literally* nothing: there is no byte code instruction inserted for it. It's an unchecked cast.

Comment: This is a type safety problem. `(T) exception` is not causing an actual type cast at runtime (I may be mistaken here, but I think the jvm doesn't actually cast to a generic type parameter)

Answer (score 3):

> What is happening here?

This code circumvents [Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2).

### Why it can be useful?

It is not always convenient to work with api that uses checked exceptions.

One of the most famous examples is [JDBC](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html). Working with jdbc always requires the developer to deal with [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/SQLException.html). But usually you don't know what you should do with the exception.

Or if you're working with library where the developers decided to inherit their exceptions from `Exception` rather than `RuntimeException`.

---

### Why checked child of `IOException` (`RemoteException`) gets converted to `RuntimeException`?

It is not converted to a `RuntimeException`.

The thrown exception is `RemoteException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.RemoteException: go unchecked!
```

The code snippet uses Java generics "tricks". Without the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` line the compiler would generate an unchecked cast warning.

### Puzzle 43

The code snippet is one of the solutions of Puzzle 43 of [Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X):

```
// Don’t do this - circumvents exception checking!
public static void sneakyThrow(Throwable t) {
    Thread.currentThread().stop(t); // Deprecated!!
}
```

> It is possible to write a method that is functionally equivalent to `sneakyThrow`
>   without using any deprecated methods. In fact, there are at least two ways to do it.
>   One of them works only in release 5.0 and later releases. Can you write such a
>   method? It must be written in Java, not in JVM bytecode. You must not change the
>   method after its clients are compiled. Your method doesn’t have to be perfect: It is
>   acceptable if it can’t throw one or two subclasses of `Exception`.

Solution from the book using generics:

```
// Don’t do this either - circumvents exception checking!
class TigerThrower<T extends Throwable> {
    public static void sneakyThrow(Throwable t) {
        new TigerThrower<Error>().sneakyThrow2(t);
    }
    private void sneakyThrow2(Throwable t) throws T {
        throw (T) t;
    }
}
```

Note on this solution from the book:

> A warning is the compiler’s way of telling you that you may be shooting yourself
>   in the foot, and in fact you are. The unchecked cast warning tells you that the
>   cast in question will not be checked at run time. When you get an unchecked
>   cast warning, modify your program to eliminate it, or convince yourself that
>   the cast cannot fail
>
> In summary, Java’s exception checking is not enforced by the virtual
>   machine. It is a compile-time facility designed to make it easier to write correct
>   programs, but it can be circumvented at run time. To reduce your exposure, do not
>   ignore compiler warnings.

---

### See also:

[`@SneakyThrows`](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows)